# How to configure vsftpd on debian 8?

Tags: linux, debian, ftp, vsftpd

I have tried many different solution that I found on the internet but none of them works.
Now my `/etc/vsftpd.conf` of vsftpd looks like this:

```
listen=NO
listen_ipv6=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
ascii_upload_enable=YES
ascii_download_enable=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
ls_recurse_enable=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
ssl_enable=NO
```

My `/etc/passwd` file

```
test:x:1003:1005:,,,:/var/www/html/test.loc/pub/media/:/bin/sh
```

`My`/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list` file

```
test
```

And when I try to log in to the server using Filezilla i get errors:

```
Response:   220 (vsFTPd 3.0.2)
Command:    USER test
Response:   331 Please specify the password.
Command:    PASS ********
Response:   530 Login incorrect.
Error:  Critical error: Could not connect to server
```

And the `systemctl -l status vsftpd.service` throws errors:

```
May 08 12:03:17 vps404990.ovh.net systemd[1]: Started vsftpd FTP server.
May 08 12:03:21 vps404990.ovh.net vsftpd[22039]: pam_unix(vsftpd:auth): check pass; user unknown
May 08 12:03:21 vps404990.ovh.net vsftpd[22039]: pam_unix(vsftpd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ftp ruser=uderkorujdom rhost=::ffff:31.182.4.210
```

I have no idea how to solve this problem. All i want to do is to create user that have access to `/var/www/html/test.loc/pub/media/` through FTP.

Answer (score 0):

I don't why but after I logged localy by `ftp 127.0.0.1` everything worked fine. After that I tried to log to the server from other host and it also worked. 
Now everything is working properly. If anyone has any idea why it worked please add comment... I would be glad to find the real answer why this worked.